# Json null pointer on setAdapter

Tags: android, json

I am new to android.I am getting NullPointerException when executing the GetData 
class which is correct.
I think problem - is wrong url or type of getting data.
JSON file: http://legs-legs.ru/cat1json.php?json=cat1

Edited code with variables

```
private ListView lv;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> newslist;

@Override
protected void  onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
...
newslist = new ArrayList<>();
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_cat1);

    new GetData().execute();
}

private class GetData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
   ...
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String url = "http://legs-legs.ru/cat1json.php?json=cat1";
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

        Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);
        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("cat1");

                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
                    String id = c.getString("id");
                    String title_cat1 = c.getString("title_cat1");
                    String fulltext_cat1 = c.getString("fulltext_cat1");

                    // tmp hash map for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> news_item = new HashMap<>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    news_item.put("id", id);
                    news_item.put("title_cat1", title_cat1);
                    news_item.put("fulltext_cat1", fulltext_cat1);
                    //contact.put("mobile", mobile);

                    // adding contact to contact list
                    newslist.add(news_item);
                }
            } catch (final JSONException e) {...

            }

        } else {...

        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainParser.this, newslist,
                R.layout.item_cat1, new String[]{ "title_cat1","fulltext_cat1"},
                new int[]{R.id.title_cat1, R.id.fulltext_cat1});
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Logcat: (stackoverflow does not allow me to format the text in the code)

```
12-27 20:18:05.341 8013-8048/? I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 11910
12-27 20:18:05.341 8013-8048/? I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
12-27 20:18:05.341 8013-8048/? I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:                                         adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app mobi.usage.appbackup
12-27 20:18:06.341 8383-8383/? I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 9452
12-27 20:18:06.341 8383-8383/? I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
12-27 20:18:06.829 8562-8612/? I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 11910
12-27 20:18:06.829 8562-8612/? I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
12-27 20:18:06.829 8562-8612/? I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
                                       adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app mobi.usage.appbackup
12-27 20:18:08.249 8958-8958/? I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 9452
12-27 20:18:08.249 8958-8958/? I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
12-27 20:18:08.985 9131-9173/? I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 11910
12-27 20:18:08.985 9131-9173/? I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
12-27 20:18:08.985 9131-9173/? I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
                                       adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app mobi.usage.appbackup
```

EDIT:
app crash on start.

```
    E/MainParser: Response from url: [{"id":"6","title_cat1":"Футболист Кокорин пострелял из пистолета на свадьбе в Осетии‍","img_cat1":"http:\/\/legs-legs.ru\/media\/image\/69ac0d3fd5efda52bbd81de7f32c77488ddd9ae4.jpg","fulltext_cat1":"<p>Нападающий санкт-петербургского Зенита Александр Кокорин пострелял из пистолета во время посещения свадьбы в Осетии. Видео в <b>инстаграме<\/b> спортсмена.<\/p>\r\n<p>Стрельбу в воздух Кокорин назвал дебютом.<\/p>\r\n<p>Ранее сообщалось, что Кокорин выложил в инстагреме фотографию с пистолетом, но позже удалил ее.<\/p>","doptext_cat1":"Любой текст"},{"id":"5","title_cat1":"Футболист Кокорин пострелял из пистолета на свадьбе в Осетии‍","img_cat1":"http:\/\/legs-legs.ru\/media\/image\/69ac0d3fd5efda52bbd81de7f32c77488ddd9ae4.jpg","fulltext_cat1":"<p>Нападающий санкт-петербургского Зенита Александр Кокорин пострелял из пистолета во время посещения свадьбы в Осетии. Видео опубликовано в <b>инстаграме<\/b> спортсмена.<\/p>\r\n<p>Стрельбу в воздух Кокорин назвал дебютом.<\/p>\r\n<p>Ранее сообщалось, что Кокорин выложил в инстагреме фотографию с пистолетом, но позже удалил ее.<\/p>","doptext_cat1":"любой текст"},{"id":"4","title_cat1":"Футболист Кокорин пострелял из пистолета на свадьбе в Осетии‍","img_cat1":"http:\/\/legs-legs.ru\/media\/image\/69ac0d3fd5efda52bbd81de7f32c77488ddd9ae4.jpg","fulltext_cat1":"<p>Нападающий санкт-петербургского Зенита Александр Кокорин пострелял из пистолета во время посещения свадьбы в Осетии. Видео опубликовано в <b>инстаграме<\/b> спортсмена.<\/p>\n<p>Стрельбу в воздух Кокорин назвал дебютом.<\/p>\n<p>Ранее сообщалось, что Кокорин выложил в инстагреме фотографию с пистолетом, но позже удалил ее.<\/p>","doptext_cat1":"Любой текст"},{"id":"3","title_cat1":"Футболист Кокорин пострелял из пистолета на свадьбе в Осетии‍","img_cat1":"http:\/\/legs-legs.ru\/media\/image\/69ac0d3fd5efda52bbd81de7f32c77488ddd9ae4.jpg","fulltext_cat1":"<p>Нападающий санкт-петербургского Зенита Александр Кокорин пострелял из пистолета во время посещения свадьбы в Осетии. Видео опубликовано в <b>инстаграме<\/b> спортсмена.<\/p>\r\n<p>Стрельбу в воздух Кокорин назвал дебютом.<\/p>\r\n<p>Ранее сообщалось, что Кокорин выложил в инстагреме фотографию с пистолетом, но позже удалил ее.<\/p>","doptext_cat1":"Любой текст"},{"id":"2","title_cat1":"Футболист Кокорин пострелял из пистолета на свадьбе в Осетии‍","img_cat1":"http:\/\/legs-legs.ru\/media\/image\/69ac0d3fd5efda52bbd81de7f32c77488ddd9ae4.jpg","fulltext_cat1":"<p>Нападающий санкт-петербургского Зенита Александр Кокорин пострелял из пистолета во время посещения свадьбы в Осетии. Видео опубликовано в <b>инстаграме
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4d75b20)
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.alexsprod.jsonparserproject, PID: 9985
                  java.lang.NullPointerException
                      at com.alexsprod.jsonparserproject.MainParser$GetData.onPostExecute(MainParser.java:139)
                      at com.alexsprod.jsonparserproject.MainParser$GetData.onPostExecute(MainParser.java:68)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                      at 

 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

1.Your List item is not defined  `Content_main_parser.xml`

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:id="@+id/flContent"
      app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
      tools:context="com.alexsprod.jsonparserproject.MainParser"
      tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main_parser">

      <ListView
          android:id="@+id/list_cat1"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/error_connecting"
          app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

  </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

2. Json Parsing error

   ```
           JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
           for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
           JSONObject c= null;
           c = array.getJSONObject(i);
           String id = c.getString("id");
           String title_cat1 = c.getString("title_cat1");
           String fulltext_cat1 = c.getString("fulltext_cat1");
           // tmp hash map for single contact
           HashMap<String, String> news_item = new HashMap<>();
           news_item.put("id", id);
           news_item.put("title_cat1", title_cat1);
           news_item.put("fulltext_cat1", fulltext_cat1);
           newslist.add(news_item);
   ```

Try the below code using volley:

3.Add Dependancy in project app->gradle

```
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
```

4.Main Activity

```
    public class MainParser extends AppCompatActivity {
        private ListView lv;
        private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> newslist;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_parser);

            newslist = new ArrayList<>();
            lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_cat1);

            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, "http://legs-legs.ru/cat1json.php?json=cat1",
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String jsonStr) {

                            try {

                                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
                                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject c = null;
                                    c = array.getJSONObject(i);
                                    String id = c.getString("id");
                                    String title_cat1 = c.getString("title_cat1");
                                    String fulltext_cat1 = c.getString("fulltext_cat1");
                                    // tmp hash map for single contact
                                    HashMap<String, String> news_item = new HashMap<>();
                                    news_item.put("id", id);
                                    news_item.put("title_cat1", title_cat1);
                                    news_item.put("fulltext_cat1", fulltext_cat1);
                                    newslist.add(news_item);
                                }
                                SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainParser.this, newslist,
                                        R.layout.item_cat1, new String[]{"title_cat1", "fulltext_cat1"},
                                        new int[]{R.id.title_cat1, R.id.fulltext_cat1});
                                lv.setAdapter(adapter);

                            } catch (final JSONException e) {

                            }


                        }

                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    System.out.println("error" + error);
                }
            });
            //Creating a Request Queue
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            //Adding request to the queue
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);


        }


    }
```

Comment: No, the same application error.
Could it be that the JSON is wrong?

Comment: I'm edit first post.
Also share project: https://github.com/AlexRU18/JsonParserProject

Comment: @AlexSuvorov I worked on the API check the latest answer I edited.

Comment: Please agree my answer if its helpful by clicking tick icon

Answer (score 2):

Change your code with below one as you get `JSONArray` in Response

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonStr);

for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
  JSONObject c= array.getJSONObject(i);
  String id = c.getString("id");
  String title_cat1 = c.getString("title_cat1");
  String fulltext_cat1 = c.getString("fulltext_cat1");

  // tmp hash map for single contact
  HashMap<String, String> news_item = new HashMap<>();

 // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
  news_item.put("id", id);
  news_item.put("title_cat1", title_cat1);
  news_item.put("fulltext_cat1", fulltext_cat1);
 //contact.put("mobile", mobile);

 // adding contact to contact list
 newslist.add(news_item);
}
```

UPDTED

Change fragement code like this way.

```
public class CatOneFragment extends Fragment {

public ListView lv;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fr_cat1, container, false);
    lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_cat1);
    new GetData().execute();
    return view;
}


class GetData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> newslist = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        //Toast.makeText("Json Data is downloading", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String url = "http://legs-legs.ru/cat1json.php?json=cat1";
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);
        newslist = new ArrayList<>();
        Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);
        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {

                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = null;
                    c = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    String id = c.getString("id");
                    String title_cat1 = c.getString("title_cat1");
                    String fulltext_cat1 = c.getString("fulltext_cat1");
                    // tmp hash map for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> news_item = new HashMap<>();
                    news_item.put("id", id);
                    news_item.put("title_cat1", title_cat1);
                    news_item.put("fulltext_cat1", fulltext_cat1);
                    newslist.add(news_item);
                }
            } catch (final JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                //CANNOT RESOLVE METHOD
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //CANNOT RESOLVE METHOD
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

            }

        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
            //CANNOT RESOLVE METHOD
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //CANNOT RESOLVE METHOD
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                            "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), newslist,
                R.layout.item_cat1, new String[]{"title_cat1", "fulltext_cat1"},
                new int[]{R.id.title_cat1, R.id.fulltext_cat1});
        //CANNOT RESOLVE SYMBOL
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: did not helps me

Comment: and where you make `newslist` variable ? i can't see in your code

Comment: @AlexSuvorov i show your code on git. you need to write a service call inside CatOneFragment fragement as your lisview is inside this fragment so move your  service call code from MainParser to CatOneFragment

Comment: can you check github? I have some errors with new code, sorry, i'm newbie. I marked them, thank you

Comment: @AlexSuvorov see my updated answer. change your fragment code

Comment: @AlexSuvorov if answer helped you then don't forgot to accept it